# Would the displacement of this question help?

Tags: support

Notwithstanding the close reason, the answers volunteered for [this question](https://superuser.com/q/679640/269574) are supernal, inestimable and efficacious, and would truly help many others. Thus, Would you please move this to softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=multiple+monitors?

**Supplementary:** Thanks. How can I obtain the input/what was typed, so that if the author here doesn't post there, I can repost his//her superlative, sterling answers and pictures?

Comment: Rather than editing your question with further questions, you should've posted a comment. Otherwise nobody gets notified and your chances of having the additional question answered become quite low. Here's the post: http://i.imgur.com/nfvyNCY.png

Comment: If you can form the other people's comments into a cohesive answer, I'd suggest posting it as an answer yourself (marking it as community wiki), and explain in the comments where you got it from

Answer (score 3):

In spite of all its glory, ahem, this question is too old to be migrated. After 60 days of asking, a question cannot be moved to another site anymore.

Consider checking with Software Recs if such a question would be acceptable there, then simply re-ask.

Comment: The only exception is that a **developer** can migrate any post and not be subject to the 60-day limit.