# Please migrate my question on Automatic Wallpaper Manager?

Tags: discussion, migration

Accordant with the answer at [Would the displacement of this question help?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8358/269574), would you please migrate https://superuser.com/questions/679640/automatic-wallpaper-manager to another apt website like Software Recs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the answer says:

> this question is too old to be migrated. After 60 days of asking, a question cannot be moved to another site anymore.
>
> Consider checking with Software Recs if such a question would be acceptable there, **then simply re-ask**.